# Problem in populating gridview from stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Gridview which I'm populating from a Stored Procedure which accepts 3 parameters. First parameter gets its value from a form variable Request.Form["uid"], second and third get its value from DropDownLists SelectedValue property. Second and third parameter should accept NULL if nothing is selected from DropDownLists. I have also set the ConvertEmptyStringToNull property of the parameters to true. 
The Gridview is still not populating. But when I pass parameters manually and execute the stored procedure from SQL Server Management Studio as well as Visual Studio's test query window, it works fine.

My SQLDataSource for the Gridview looks like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlGVDownloadHistory" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:xxx %>"
            SelectCommand="spDHR" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:FormParameter FormField="uid" Name="UIDUser" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlSelectDocument" Name="FileName"
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlSelectCCO" Name="UIDSelect" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                    Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Please help!!

Comment: thanks for this tip Naveen. I am new to this forum, so was not aware of this.

Comment: thought so. you were very responsive to the answers

Comment: Can you show your markup for your gridview? Have you verified that you tied you the gridview's datasource to the one you created? Could you also, at least, show the names of the parameters for your stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlGVDownloadHistory" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:xxx %>" 
            SelectCommand="spDHR"
            SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
            OnSelecting="SqlGVDownloadHistory_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="uid" Name="UIDUser" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And on Code Behind

```
protected void SqlGVDownloadHistory_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    SqlGVDownloadHistory.SelectParameters.Remove("FileName");
    SqlGVDownloadHistory.SelectParameters.Remove("UIDSelect");
    if (ddlSelectDocument.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        SqlGVDownloadHistory.SelectParameters.Add("FileName", ddlSelectDocument.SelectedValue);
    }
    if (ddlSelectCCO.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        SqlGVDownloadHistory.SelectParameters.Add("UIDSelect", ddlSelectCCO.SelectedValue);
    }
}
```

The idea is to set the parameters before the data retrieval operation occurs.

As per [MSDN documentation on COntrolParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt50s8kz.aspx), I don't see `asp:DropDownList` `Selectedvalue` being set as a `ControlValuePropertyAttribute`

Comment: I tried but it is not working. I have set default value of FileName and UIDSelect parameters as NULL in the database. 

When I was configuring the SQLDataSource for the Gridview, I was given the option of choosing DropDownList as the control from where to fetch the parameter value.

Comment: yeah i tht msdn missed that out. but the problem is that you really don't have a way to set parameters based on selected index unless you are programmatically setting that.

Comment: but it is still not working. I debugged using watch for the parameters. All the values are showing as NULL and no row is being returned.

Comment: Executing your code gives the error "procedure has too many arguments specified". This is because the parameters are getting added multiple times.

Comment: updated code. you should be fine if you have assigned null in the stored procedure. i have not used SqlDataSource for a long time. please get backif issue persist

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the default value for your two input parameters on your stored procedure to null.

Comment: I've already done that. After doing that, if I populate the Gridview using code-behind (using dataset and SqlDataAdapter), it works fine. But in that case, I'll have to handle the PageIndexChanged and other events manually. That's the reason I want to do it using the graphical interface.

Comment: there's minimal lines of code required to handle multiple pages in gridview I can show you an example if you need including adding number tabs on the gridview

Comment: That would be very helpful. I tried one of the examples from the net, but it is causing the problem of null DataSource after postbacks.